# What edition of Scalzi's The Human Division contains all the original artwork?

Tags: books, novel, john-scalzi

I am starting to read John Scalzi's novel "The Human Division". It appears to be made up of thirteen distinct chapters named "episodes".

In the acknowledgments, he praises the cover artist:

> Cover artist John Harris's contribution to *The Human Division* is significant enough that I have codedicated the entire book to him, but I want to acknowledge again his spectacular work for the book and for the individual episodes.

The edition of the book I have is a 19.5cm x 13cm paperback published in 2016 by Tor. Except for the cover on the outside of the book, I'm not seeing any illustrations in there.

While I usually do not expect any graphical content in a novel, I am feeling a tiny little bit cheated right now, especially as the acknowledgments go on to say:

> The book would not be the same without his efforts.

**What edition(s) would I need to see all the artwork created for the book?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*The Human Division*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1542905) was initially released as a set of 13 chapbooks.  I assume he's talking about the covers for each of those chapbooks, which you can see in [this gallery](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1542905); they are all credited to John Harris.

Here are the first 2 chapbook covers as an example of the artwork:

[image: The B-Team, The Human Division episode 1]
[image: Walk the Plank, The Human Division episode 2]

It appears that prints of some of these may be available from the [website of his representative](http://www.alisoneldred.com/thumbsJohnHarris-Prints-2-1.html), for example, here is the original art for [the cover of episode 6](http://www.alisoneldred.com/imageJohnHarris-Prints-2-2502.html):

[image: The Twin Parliaments of Pyrrhus by John Harris]

I didn't initially recognize his work but he's also the artist for [Ann Leckie's Imperial Radch](http://www.alisoneldred.com/imageJohnHarris-Prints-2-2061.html) trilogy

Comment: For now, it looks like the original edition as separate "chapbooks" is the safest/most regular way, so I'll accept this answer. With this explanation of why there is per-chapter artwork, I don't really expect there to be a special edition book with all chapters and all the graphics inside.